# change color of UILabel in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am having a small issue with changing of a `UILabel` `textColor` property, it does not change color within the `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I am using a customCell that is SubClassed and

I am using the latest XCode4 GM version and was wondering if anyone else is experiencing anything similar
or perhaps its a bug in the version of xcode

UPDATE:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(HSCustomCellTF *)[[textField superview] superview]];
  HSCustomCellTF *cell = (HSCustomCellTF *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.keyLBL.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
  cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelectedBG.png"]] autorelease];

  tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

  return YES;
}
```

I would like to add that I have tried in other methods to achieve the result but with no luck,
I am going to now try the `willDisplayCell` method and see how that goes, thanks for the help.

Also the backgroundView does change properly so I am accessing the cell

Comment: Could you provide the code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

from UITableViewDelegate Protocol

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate

Comment: this is not working, i think because I am not editing the table, I have a uilabel and uitextfield and the TF is hidden and I use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method to update the label, i am using this because I dont want the user to enter a decimal and the value is a price

Comment: ok after a little investigation, you are correct that this is the method to do it in, but it is still not update the lables color, any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the answer, it seems that when you are using a custom cell, and you want to edit the labels color, then in the subclass of the tableViewCell, DO NOT set the property in the layoutSubviews method, once I removed the textColor property from that method @gkchristopher answer is correct, thank you all for your help, hopefully this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return indexPath;
}
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return indexPath;
}
```